# TypeError: abspath() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: c++, python, networking

I get this error while running a python script (called by ./waf --run):
TypeError: abspath() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

The problem is that it is indeed called with: obj.path.abspath(env).

This is not a python issue, because that code worked perfectly before, and it's part of a huge project (ns3) so I doubt this is broken.

However something must have changed in my settings, because this code worked before, and now it doesn't.

Can you help me to figure out why I get this error ?

Here is the python code: http://pastebin.com/EbJ50BBt. The error occurs line 61.

Comment: A bit of the code where the error occurs would be welcome...

Comment: @emmanuel: Yeah, it's getting annoying. People are asking for help/comment, but never show us where they problem lies! Like we are prophets! ;-)

Comment: `obj.path.abspath()` is a method of the object `obj.path` – whatever type this object might have.  Since the instance is implicitly passed as the first parameter to a method, the method is indeed called with two parameters.  Check the documentation of the library this method belongs to, or at least tell us what this library might be.

Comment: emmanuel, don question: see edit for the python code.
sven marnach: no I am just using c++ code, but I'm using waf to run my program (which builds successfully), and waf calls this wscript.py file where this error occurs.

Comment: Why do you feel that the `C++` tag is appropriate? Removing it.

Comment: As I said, this is a NS3 project (uses c++ only). I programmed a small program which is in C++ only, there's no python in what I did. However, in order to run my code (which compiles), I need to call waf, which in turn calls this wscript python script. Now there are two possibilities: either the professional guys who created this very sophisticated network simulator made a bug in one of the core files of the code they use every day, or me, a total newbie, made an error in my c++ code or in the way I'm running my code. I'm gonna go with the second solution. This is why there's a c++ tag.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of the method [`Node.abspath()`](http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/apidocs_16/Node.html#waflib.Node.Node.abspath) states it does not take an additional `env` parameter, and I confirmed that it never did by checking the git history.  I suggest replacing

```
if not (obj.path.abspath().startswith(launch_dir)
        or obj.path.abspath(env).startswith(launch_dir)):
    continue
```

with

```
if not obj.path.abspath().startswith(launch_dir):
    continue
```

If this code worked before, this is probably due to the fact that the first operator of the `or` expression happened to always be `True`, so the second operator was never executed.  It seems to be a bug in your code anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately, it doesn't work either, although the error is different. It now says "program 'test' not found; available programs are: []", although test.cc is in the scratch folder, so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a file name and line number in the traceback. Go to that file and line and find out was "obj" and "obj.path.abspath" are. A simple solution would be to put the offending line in a try/except block to print (or log) more informations, ie:

```
# your code here
try:
    whatever = obj.path.abspath(env)
except Exception, e:
    # if you have a logger
    logger.exception("oops : obj is '%s' (%s)" % (obj, type(obj)))
    # else 
    import sys
    print >> sys.stderr, "oops, got %s on '%s' (%s)" % (e, obj, type(obj))
    # if you can run this code directly from a shell,
    # this will send you in the interactive debugger so you can
    # inspect the offending objet and the whole call stack.
    # else comment out this line
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    # and re-raise the exception
    raise
```

My bet is that "obj.path" is NOT the python 'os.path' module, and that "obj.path.abspath" is a an instance method that only takes "self" as argument.

Comment: I have added the whole code in my edit so that you can see what obj.path is. But as I said, I don't think this error comes from a bug in the script, but rather from the way my settings are made. I have been able to run this script successfully before (this python script is called by ./waf --run), and I don't know what changed since

Comment: `obj` is returned by `bld.all_task_gen`, and there's no definition of obj's class in your code snippet so no, we _cannot see_ what `obj.path` is. The only thing we know is that it's supposed to have an 'is_ns3_program' attribute having a true value.

Also, `bld` is only bound once in your script, and it's bound to `None` (IOW it cannot run without some other code importing it and rebinding `bld` to something supposedly "usable" which is IMHO a _very_ bad design) so we don't even know what `bld` is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from the fact that apparently waf doesn't like symlinks, the python code must not be prepared for such cases.

Problem solved, thanks for your help everybody